# Merge and match oracle

Tags: oracle, merge, match

I really need some help with my query. I am trying to merge two tables together, but I only want the data were Cast_Date and Sched_Cast_Date are the same. I try to run the query but I get the error missing keyword in the line 21 column 13. I am sure that this is not the only potential error that I have. Could someone help me to get this query up and running? Below is the query that I am running.

```
merge into Dante5 d5
using (SELECT 
bbp.subcar treadwell, bbp.BATCH_ID batch_id,
bcs.SILICON silicon,
bcs.SULPHUR sulphur,
bcs.MANGANESE manganese,
bcs.PHOSPHORUS phosphorus,
bofcs.temperature temperature,
to_char(bbp.START_POUR, 'dd-MON-yy hh24:MI') start_pour,
to_char(bbp.END_POUR, 'dd-MON-yy hh24:MI') end_pour,
to_char(bbp.sched_cast_date, 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi') Sched_cast_date
FROM  bof_chem_sample bcs, bof_batch_pour bbp, bof_celox_sample bofcs
WHERE bcs.SAMPLE_CODE= to_char('D1')
and bofcs.sample_code=bcs.sample_code
and bofcs.batch_id=bcs.batch_id
and bcs.batch_id = bbp.batch_id
and bofcs.temperature>0
AND bbp.START_POUR>=to_DATE('01012011000000','ddMmyyyyHH24MISS')
and bbp.sched_cast_date<=sysdate)d3
ON (d3.sched_cast_date=d5.sched_cast_date)
when matched then
delete where (d5 sched_cast_date>=to_date('18012011','ddmmyyyy'))
when not matched 
then 
update
set d5=batch_id='99999'
```

Comment: What does it mean to you to merge two tables together?  Normally, when there is a match, you update the destination table and when there is not a match you insert into the destination table.  Here, you are never inserting into the destination table.  And you will never update the destination table because, by definition, if there is no match, there is no row in the destination table to update.  What version of Oracle are you using?  Oracle added the optional DELETE clause to 10g (and made both the WHEN MATCHED and WHEN NOT MATCHED clauses optional) but deleting on a match seems odd.

Comment: @Justin why did you choose to comment rather than answer?

Comment: @Conrad - I'm trying to understand the requirements before I get too far into addressing the syntax.  I was trying to point out how the current syntax is muddying the requirements.

Comment: I would like to combine the two tables into a single table with all of the columns from both tables along with all of the data matched on the constraint that d5.sched_cast_date=d3.sched_cast_date. I am not sure if this is how merege works, but that is what I am looking to do. If I am misleaded, could you help me with that?

Comment: I'm still not understanding.  Do you want to create a third table?  Or do you want all the data to reside in the `DANTE5` table?  Does `DANTE5` already have all the columns the final table needs?  Or are you saying that you want to add additional columns?  It would probably help to post the table definitions, DML to insert some sample data into both, and the result that is expected after the tables are merged.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is invalid to start with. If you specify WHEN MATCHED, you are required to specify WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET col=value. For the WHEN NOT MATCHED you must specify WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT. [See the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm) for more information.